# Firestore : Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Recently I have received this crash from users on Crashlytics:

```
PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java line 39
io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).
   at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:324)
   at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzd.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

Caused by java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier:  a
   at java.util.Formatter.getArgument(Formatter.java:1111)
   at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1076)
   at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1042)
   at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1011)
   at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1554)
   at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1528)
   at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzr.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:29)
   at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzr.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:44)
   at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.zzk.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:169)
   at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.zzk.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:124)
   at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.zzo.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:9381)
   at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.zza.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:290)
   at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.zza.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:347)
   at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.zza$zzb.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:104)
   at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzm$1.onClose(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:104)
   at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
   at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
   at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
   at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:684)
   at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
   at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
   at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
   at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:391)
   at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:1471)
   at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:1553)
   at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:591)
   at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
   at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
   at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza$zza.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:190)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This crash some times reach as:

```
Caused by java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'p'
```

I cannot reproduce this crash but it seems that this function is responsible for it : com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza(..)

```
  private static void zza(int var0, String var1, String var2, Object... var3) {
    if (var0 - 1 >= zza - 1) {
        var1 = String.format("(%s) [%s]: ", "0.6.6-dev", var1) + String.format(var2, var3);
        switch(null.zza[var0 - 1]) {
        case 1:
            Log.i("Firestore", var1);
            return;
        case 2:
            Log.w("Firestore", var1);
            return;
        case 3:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Trying to log something on level NONE");
        }
    }

}
```

FiresStore version : com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0

My code uses normal firestore operation such get, set, transactions. I am also using firebase-UI-firestore for query list.

Why this crash happened and how to solve it?

Comment: This sounds like something to ask firebase support directly.

Comment: @AndréKool where to ask them ,could you provide me with firestore github link so I can post this problem to them?

Comment: I think [this](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank for your comment,  I think I will open an issue at firebase github project.